# How to display NERDtree buffer in a floating window

Tags: neovim, plugin-nerdtree

Thanks to a comment on reddit I was able to move my FZF search to a floating window and whilst it looks cool my main gain was that it's faster or at least it feels faster because it's no longer messing with my splits.

So I Was wondering, would it be possible to display NERDtree in floating window?

If so How?

I've looked through NERDtree's source code but I can't find the functionality to intercept/override to provide my own custom functionality for where to display NERDTree's buffer.

Comment: It is doable in neo-tree and it works great. Also to me neo-tree is more aesthetic.